# Stepwise Regression & Cross validation in R | Code explanation

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

I'm a novice in R and I'd like to perform some feature selection using stepwise regression.

Therefore, I'd like to apply the following code using the caret package

```
# Set up repeated k-fold cross-validation
train.control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)
# Train the model
step.model <- train(Fertility ~., data = swiss,
              method = "lmStepAIC",
              trControl = train.control,
              trace = FALSE
              )
# Model accuracy
step.model$results
# Final model coefficients
step.model$finalModel
# Summary of the model
summary(step.model$finalModel)
```

However, I don't quite understand the "connection" between the cross-validation and lmStepAIC (which, I know, returns the best performing model as determined by the AIC criterion). How is this linked by trControl, i.e. how does this work?

Any help is very appreciated!

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Maybe you have to do it because of an assignment, but it's generally advised not to use stepwise regression https://journalofbigdata.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40537-018-0143-6

Comment: That's an interesting comment! I haven't read about that. But what you suggest to do in order to reduce the number of features for a prediction problem then?

Comment: I would check out lasso regression or bayesian variable selection